If we spin an ostrich egg along its minor axis will it be oblate shape?
An ostrich egg is classified as an ellipsoid and if we spin it around it's major axis it's classified as a prolate but my fried is arguing that we can not spin that ellipsoid around its minor axis because then "it won't be symmetrical around the axis" and this has confused me.
Basically I want to know if the same ellipsoid rotated about minor axis
that was categorized as oblate, can also be categorized as prolate when we rotate it about the major axis.

The Earth, which is not truly a rigid object, has acquired an oblate shape due to its spin. That is, the minor axis of the Earth exists because of its rotation. But the ostrich egg is (approximately?) a prolate ellipsoid when it is not spinning. Why do you say "if we spin it" it is classified as prolate?

If you consider objects that won't be deformed by rotation, you can spin an ellipsoid about any of its principal axes. The result is you get the same ellipsoid spinning about an axis, not a new shape.

@DavidK from what I've heard from Wikipedia if we spin an ellipsoid along minor axis it's oblate. And if we spin the ellipsoid along major axis it's oblate. But I wanted to clarify does this mean we can just change the type of ellipsoid (prolate to oblate) just by changing the axis from major toinor axis, the axis of rotation that is

@DavidK I ment, I read on wiki that ellipsoid can be 1. Polate 2. Oblate. But I wasn't sure what difference is there apart from axis of rotation

I looked at the Wikipedia article on ellipsoids and the only time the word "spin" occurs in any form is under the heading "dynamical properties." Why did you write "spin" in the question? Even the word "rotation" needs to be carefully used. "Axis of rotation" is a completely different thing from "axis of rotational symmetry".

You really must read Wiki more carefully  and quote it accurately. It says that if one rotates an ELLIPSE about its major/minor axis then one gets a prolate/oblate spheroid.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid

@ancientmathematician Thanks man I will be better next time. I think my confusion is almost done, just verify that it is possible for a prolate to turn into an oblate IF we change e the axis along which the ELLIPSE is rotating. Appreciate it man

Well prolate  doesn't change into oblate: they're two distinct 3-d shapes we get by rotating the 2-d ellipse about different axes.

So if we have an ellipsoid. When we rotate that ellipsoid along the minor axis it's called an oblate. But when we rotate the same ellipsoid along the major axis it falls under the prolate category.

Basically the same ellipsoid can fall under the oblete category and the prolate category depending upon the direction of rotation. If it rotates about the minor axis the ellipsoid is oblete and if it rotates about the major axis it's prolate. Correct?

It's not the same ellipsoid. That's the fundamental issue of this discussion. A prolate ellipsoid is a prolate ellipsoid, an oblate ellipsoid is an oblate ellipsoid, and an ellipse is not an ellipsoid at all.

All this talk of turning prolate ellipsoids into oblate ellipsoids makes the same kind of sense as turning a Toyota into a Volkswagen by building it in Germany instead of Japan. In reality, you simply don't change Toyotas into Volkswagens, even though they are both cars. There's a company that build Toyotas, and there's a company that builds Volkswagens.

@DavidK - As I understand the question, it asks whether a prolate spheroid can also be an oblate spheroid, when viewed from a different perspective. Though the answer is "no", it is a sensible question. The terms "spin" and "rotate" are referring either to an arbitrary coordinate axis, or to the ellipsoid's symmetry, not to its construction from an ellipse.

@ancientmathematician - See previous comment

@mr_e_man How do you get "different perspective" from "spin that ellipsoid around its minor axis"? The question is simply nonsensical, that's all. We can try to guess what OP had in mind when asking it, but only OP knows and they have not yet clarified their meaning sufficiently. OP says, "So if we have an ellipsoid. When we rotate that ellipsoid along the minor axis it's called an oblate." Perhaps if OP would actually quote verbatim from some source from which they got these words, we'd be able to explain what the words actually meant and how to assemble them into a meaningful statement.

Forget about spinning. An ellipsoid has three perpendicular axes; it can be constructed from a sphere, by stretching it along these axes. The stretch factors may or may not be equal.
It's called a spheroid if two axes are equal. It's prolate if the two equal axes are shorter than the third axis. It's oblate if the two equal axes are longer than the third axis. They cannot both be true at the same time.

Notwithstanding our contretemps in comments under the question, I agree with this answer completely and find it useful. It has the advantage over other explanations in that it avoids the language that appears to be confusing the question-asker. +1

An ellipse will make two differently shaped ellipsoids when revolved around its minor vs. major axis unless it is a circle, in which case it will create a sphere in both cases.  So yes, it can form a prolate spheroid by revolving around the major axis and an oblate spheroid by revolving around the minor axis, but the two ellipsoids will not be congruent as long as the major axis is longer than the minor axis (i.e. it's not a circle).
